# Remove Hashtag from Location.Hash

Tags: jquery, hash, window.location

Is there a way to remove # symbol in the URL for the below code?

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var hashLink = "?" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
    location.hash = hashLink;  
});
```

If I enter the name "David" within the Input, I receive the below response within the URL.

http://localhost:51746/#?FirstName=David

I have tried to put .substring(1) at the end of hashLink but it only removes the ? symbol.

Is there an easy way to remove # while diplaying the string for var hashLink?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's what a hash is, the `#` symbol. If you want to just set the querystring you do that by changing the `location.search` not the hash, but that does reload the page, as it should

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (event) {
    var hashLink = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();

    window.location.search = hashLink;  
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to set the querystring without reloading the page since I want this to coincide with an ajax request.  I wasn't sure if there is a way to use substring or slice to remove the hash.  I've tried multiple ways but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: There's no easy way to change the URL without reloading the page, other than changing the hash, and the hash requires the use of the `#` character, that's what telling the browser to not reload the page, so you can't remove that and change the URL without redirecting the browser. Well, you could if you used the History API, but that's all together different.